# Applescript used in compiled app won't access ML Calendar

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion, realbasic

I write RealBasic apps for use on my own computer only. I have a few scripts that access Contacts and Calendar data. All of these scripts work great and Mountain Lion (ML) even automatically updated the application names for me.

The same scripts also run from within a compiled RealBasic app I wrote (a client booking system) that need to run from here as they have arguments passed to them. The ones that access Contacts caused ML to ask for permission the first time they ran, and then everything worked fine. But those that access Calendar never asked for permission and of course, don't run at all - so my main controlling app is broken.

I am aware of Apple's new AppleScript restrictions - but given the above Contacts behavior, clearly there is a way to allow programs to be controlled by AppleScripts.

Is there any way I can tell Calendar to allow the script to run? (Contacts has this in the Security settings in ML's settings app, but there is no entry for Calendar.)

(I am a private hobbyist not a developer so I am not verified, signed and sealed!)